# titleps' page styles inserted just before chapters start too early

Tags: header-footer, chapters, titlesec, titleps

The following MCE and image show that titleps' page styles inserted just before chapters start too early: the head rule begins with the 'test' page style which should be applied only after the end of chapter 1 and, hence, at beginning of chapter 2.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\newpagestyle{main}[]{%
  \sethead
  [\thepage][][\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter. \chaptertitle]
  {\ifthesection{\thesection\space\,\sectiontitle}
  {\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter. \chaptertitle}}{}{\thepage}
}
%
\newpagestyle{test}[]{%
  \sethead
  [\thepage][][\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter. \chaptertitle]
  {\ifthesection{\thesection\space\,\sectiontitle}
  {\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter. \chaptertitle}}{}{\thepage}
  \headrule
}
%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{main}
\chapter{Main}
\lipsum[1-25]
\pagestyle{test}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

As shown by the following image, adding a `\cleardoublepage` at the beginning of `\newpagestyle{test}` doesn't help:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `\cleardoublepage` to the page style definitions doesn't help, because page styles are applied during the output routine.

Add `\cleardoublepage` before the pagestyle change; you may want to define a `\switchpagestyle` command:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\switchpagestyle}{%
  \@ifstar{\clearpage\pagestyle}{\cleardoublepage\pagestyle}}
\makeatother
```

so that you can type

```
\switchpagestyle{test}
```

if you want also a `\cleardoublepage` or

```
\switchpagestyle*{test}
```

if only a `\clearpage` is needed.

Comment: That does the trick. In your answer, the first `\makeatletter` should be `\makeatother`. If only `\cleardoublepage`, another possibility is to redefine `\pagestyle` with something like `\let\origpagestyle\pagestyle%
\renewcommand{\pagestyle}{%
  \cleardoublepage%
  \origpagestyle%
}
`

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I wouldn't change `\pagestyle`. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.